# Derivation of the Poisson Kernel from the Cauchy Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the disk

$$ D_{r_0} =\{z\in\ {C} : |z|<R_0 \}
$$
centered at the origin and of radius $R_0$. $$$$
Prove that whenever $0<R<R_0$ and $|z|<R$, then
$$f(z) =\frac{1}{2π}\ \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(Re^{i\phi}) 
Re \bigl ( \frac {Re^{i\phi}+z}{Re^{i\phi}-z} \bigr) d \phi.
$$
  and the lecture note start with below

$$
f(z) =\frac{1}{2πi}\ \int_{|ζ|=R} \frac{f(ζ)}{ζ−z}\
dζ.
$$

$$
0 =\frac{1}{2πi}\ \int_{|ζ|=R} \frac{f(ζ)}{ ζ−\frac{R^2}{\bar{z}} }\
dζ. 
$$

My lecture note says that the second equation holds by Cauchy Theorem. But
I don't know why the second equation is equal to zero.$\frac{R^2}{\bar{z}}$ could be on the disk which means ${|ζ|=R}$. Am I wrong?.

Comment: Where does $D_{R_0}$ appear, in your lecture notes? It seems you never use it.

Comment: I don't exactly see how the term $\frac{R^2}{\bar{z}}$ comes up. More specifically, is the second equation supposed to hold for any choice of $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equation hods for $|z|<R$. I assume that in the third equation we also have $|z|<R$. Then $|R^2/\bar z|>R$ and the function
$$
\frac{f(z)}{z-R^2/\bar z}
$$
is holomorphic on an open set containing $\{|z|\le R\}$. Cauchy's Theorem implies that the integral is zero.