# $f(z)$ is real if $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is entire and maps the unit circle to the real line. Prove that $f(z)$ is real if $|z|<1$.

I have shown that $f(0)$ is real by Cauchy integral formula but using the same formula I can't see that $f(z)$ would be real. Can someone give me a hint on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: A function which is real in the entire unit disc would be constant.

Comment: Hint: consider the minimum and maximum of $\text{Im}(f(z))$ on the unit disk.

Comment: @Martin R, by Maximum modulus principle, $f$ is bounded on the unit disc. Thus f being constant follow from Liouville?

Comment: Louieville's theorem states that every bounded entire function must be constant. That is, every holomorphic function $f$ for which there exists a positive number $M$ such that $| f ( z ) | \leq M$ for all $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is constant. You need to show that $f$ is bounded on the unit disk.

Comment: A proper answer to your question depends on  what tools are at your disposal. In  which context was the problem posed? Are you familar with the Poisson integral, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/207067/42969? Or do you know the maximum principle for harmonic functions? – That $f$ is necessarily constant can be concluded from the open mapping theorem,  but also from the Schwarz reflection principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w \in \mathbb{C}$, $\lvert w \rvert < 1$ and consider $$g(z)=f\left(\frac{z+w}{1+\overline{w}z}\right).$$ Then $g$ is holomorphic on a disc with radius $>1$, real-valued on the unit circle, and $g(0)=f(w)$.

Or directly from Cauchy’s, using that $\overline{z}=z^{-1}$ if $\lvert z \rvert=1$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
f(w) &= &\frac1{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\int_{\lvert z \rvert = 1}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}\mathrm{d}z \\[1em]&= &\overline{\frac{-1}{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\int_{\lvert z \rvert = 1}\frac{z f(z)}{1-\overline{w}z}\mathrm{d}z^{-1}} \\[1em]&= &\overline{\frac1{2\pi \mathrm{i}}\int_{\lvert z \rvert = 1}\frac{f(z)}{z(1-\overline{w}z)}\mathrm{d}z} = \overline{f(0)}
\end{eqnarray}$$ so that $f$ is constant on the unit disc.